# How can I print consecutive integers greater than 0, three per line?

Tags: java, for-loop

**How to loop this?**

I'm trying to loop this:

```
0-> 1,2,3
1-> 4,5,6
2-> 7,8,9
3-> 10,11,12
4->.....
......
```

I don't know how to write this algorithm.
I tried below, it doesn't work.

```
public class gYie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int current = 0;
        int death = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "    ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(death+j +" ");

                current += j;
            }
            death += current;
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Its Output is:

```
run:
0    0 1 2 
1    3 4 5 
2    9 10 11 
3    18 19 20 
4    30 31 32 
5    45 46 47 
6    63 64 65 
7    84 85 86 
8    108 109 110 
9    135 136 137
```

How to solve this? I can't think how to write it.
3 becomes 18,19,20 instead of 12,13,14.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: Check my ans for a solution which uses only one loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this. Just keep printing the `current`.

```
   int current = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "    ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(current +" ");
            current ++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking it. For the left-hand side, all you need to print is `i`. For the right-hand side , you just need a single variable `current` that gets incremented every time its printed:

```
int current = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + "    ");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        System.out.print(current + " ");

        current ++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks suspiciously like homework, so here's some pseudo-code (actually Python)  that will do the trick for you:

```
for outer in range (10):
    print "%d ->"%(outer),
    for inner in range (3):
        print "%2d"%(outer * 3 + inner + 1),
    print
```

The basic idea is to simply have an inner loop of 0 through 2 inclusive and an outer loop that increases by one each time. Then the formula:

```
outer * 3 + inner + 1
```

gives you the values you want:

```
0 ->  1  2  3
1 ->  4  5  6
2 ->  7  8  9
3 -> 10 11 12
4 -> 13 14 15
5 -> 16 17 18
6 -> 19 20 21
7 -> 22 23 24
8 -> 25 26 27
9 -> 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int loopCount = 1;

for(int a = 1; a < 21; a++){
    System.out.println(a);
    for(int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
        System.out.print((loopCount++) + " ");  
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Edit:** But I guess I found a more efficient way by using a single loop

```
int x = 1;

for(int a = 0; a < 21; a++){    
    System.out.println(a + " -> " + (x) + " " + (x + 1) + " " + (x + 2));   
    x = x + 3;
}
```

now you can merge it with your variables and logic

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a single loop:

```
int n = 15;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simplify your code as follows :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int death = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "    ");
        death = 3*i;
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {

            System.out.print(death+j +" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

}

You will now get the output as :-

```
0    1 2 3 
1    4 5 6 
2    7 8 9 
3    10 11 12 
4    13 14 15 
5    16 17 18 
6    19 20 21 
7    22 23 24 
8    25 26 27 
9    28 29 30
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job...

```
public class gYie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "    ");
            for (int h = 0; h < 3; h++, j++) {
                System.out.print(j +" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple counter:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(i + "    " + ++j + " " + ++j + " " + ++j + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of nested loops above. Here's a scalable solution within a single for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbersPerLine = 3;
    int finalNumber = 12;
    int startingRowNumber = 0;
    System.out.print(startingRowNumber + " -> ");
    for(int i = 0; i < finalNumber; i++) {
        if(i > 0 && (i % numbersPerLine) == 0) {
            System.out.print("\n" + ((i / numbersPerLine) + startingRowNumber) + " -> ");
        } else if(i > 0) {
            System.out.print(",");            
        }
        System.out.print((i + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code like this.

```
int death = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
System.out.print(i + "    ");
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    System.out.print(death++ +" ");

    //current += j;
    }
    //death += current;
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Got exact solution for it ...

```
class Alok{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int i = 0,j=0;
         for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        System.out.print(""+i+"->");
        for(j=(i*3)+1;j<(i*3)+4;j++){
            System.out.print(""+j+" ");
        }System.out.println();
         }
    }
}
```